# Sticky table headers not maintaining width when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make the table header sticky at the top when scrolled down.

I am using the solution provided here: css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/.

However when I try to use it, the table header does not maintain its width.

```js
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
       $(".persist-area").each(function() {
           var el             = $(this),
               offset         = el.offset(),
               scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
               floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)
           if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
               floatingHeader.css({
                "visibility": "visible"
               });
           } else {
               floatingHeader.css({
                "visibility": "hidden"
                 });      
               };
           });
        }
            
        $(function() {
           var clonedHeaderRow;
           $(".persist-area").each(function() {
               clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
               clonedHeaderRow
                 .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
                 .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
                 .addClass("floatingHeader");  
           });
           $(window)
            .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
            .trigger("scroll");
        });
```

```css
.floatingHeader {
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       visibility: hidden;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="persist-area">
          <tr class="persist-header">
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
          </tr>
       </table>
```

How do I make the table columns aligned and look natural?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you put `position: fixed;` on your cloned header row it is no longer in the context of the table since it is `fixed`. Meaning that the header cell widths will not assume the width of the data cell widths because the fixed header is no longer part of the table.

Even though you are setting the width of your cloned header to match that of the "not fixed" header row, the cells will only take up the width of their cell content if no width is set. Thus you get that "collapsed" look in your image.

To fix this you will need to explicitly set the cell widths of your `.floatingHeader` to match the cell width of the table cells. You will also need to set the `display` of your `.floatingHeader` to `table` so that it behaves like a table, because remember it is no longer in the context of the table.

So your updated CSS might look like this:

```
.floatingHeader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: table; /*Added*/
}

.floatingHeader th,
.persist-area th,
.persist-area td {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  width: 33%; /*All cells must match widths*/
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ak36e2v6/1/) for a demo.

**UPDATE**

To sync the header size with the table on browser window resize you can attach an event that sync's the widths of the fixed header and the original header:

```
   $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(".persist-header").width();
        $(".floatingHeader").width(w);
    });
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ak36e2v6/2/) for a demo (resize the frame window)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise it's the position: fixed problem. Was writing lines of js and jquery trying to fix it!

Comment: Hmm, after scrolling the sticky table header doesn't scale and change width when I change the window size like the table does. Any idea?

Comment: You can try to give it `width: 100%;`, and see if that works (you will have to remove where you set the width in javascript tho, a style set in javascript will be an inline style and will take precedence over the one you write in css). If that doesn't work you might have to create a `$(window).resize(function() { })` event and update the fixed headers width to match, like you are currently doing on scroll

Comment: Do you mind teaching me more on the $(window).resize(function() { })? I've tried width:100% and didn't work - when window gets resized the table headers width aren't matched with table contents below. Many thanks!

Comment: You helped another dude, 5 years later. Much kudos, an I hope you are still doing well

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
left: 0
right: 0
width: 100%
```

to your `.floatingHeader` class

Comment: She is setting the width dynamically in javascript here: `.css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())`